# Can we write a macro in C# for Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have to traverse about 25 sheets in excel for doing operations.I'm doing it using vba and finding it really slow,hence wanted to know if I could use C# and if doing that would help me speed up the process.

Comment: I don't think you can use C# directly in a macro.  
You can create an AddIn written in C# to work with the sheet.  

If it speeds up your process can't be answered until you describe what you're doing.

Comment: C# vs VBA ... compiled code vs interpreted, the latter will almost always be slower.  Same goes for javascript for Excel.  You would need a compiled application (.NET Core, etc.) that could read in your Excel file, process it, and save it.

Answer (score 51):

Call C# from Excel workbook like VBA macro - you can't

Access Excel workbook from C# application - you can. This is called Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office ([VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsto+excel))

Comment: Speak like Yoda - you do

Comment: I would disagree. You can call a (C#) web service via a macro. I think the same applies to restful endpoints written in webapi ...

Comment: @cs0815 the call would be likely written in VBA or C with a help of COM, wouldn't be? So still no C# (to my knowledge).

Comment: I am talking about some functionality written in C# and exposed as soap web service or restful endpoint. Such web services can be invoked by VBA (e.g. http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19-STEP-BY-STEP-Consuming-Web-Services-through-VBA-Excel-or-Word-Part-I.aspx) so you can run c# "inside" Excel. You can also write a workbook app in C# via VSTO so you can literally use C# code in a workbook (vs solution) (-:

Answer (score 12):

Although you may be able to write an equivalent in C# to your current VBA macro using VSTO, I doubt very much if it would make any significant difference to performance.

In both cases, you'll be manipulating the same Excel COM objects and the execution time is likely to be very similar.

Your performance will depend mainly on the techniques you are using to manipulate the Excel objects.  As a simple example, you can assign values from an Excel Range to a 2-dimensional array in a single statement: this is much faster than iterating through the rows and columns in code and copying values into your array one by one.

I'd recommend you post bits of the VBA code that you find too slow, and ask for tips on improving performance.

Answer (score 7):

You can try my [ESharper](https://vlasovstudio.com/esharper/) add-in to write an Excel automation command in C#. It is easier than creating a separate C# application or an add-in, and you will have access to both Excel object model and Excel C API with more options for performance optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer says "no", but I beg to differ.

There is no native way, true, but there is a plugin called QueryStorm that lets you use C# in Excel, in much the same way you would use VBA.

Here's what the plugin looks like in action...

LINQ querying Excel tables:
[image]

Debugging a custom Excel function written in C#:
[image]

It has a debugger, NuGet support and even an app store. I've described it in more detail in [this blog post](https://querystorm.com/csharp-in-excel/).

It's a paid product but offers free community licenses which unlock most features. The free license is for individuals and small companies (not more than 5 employees and not more than $1M annual revenue).

Disclaimer: I'm the author.