# Excel Macros in other Languages

Tags: excel

Is there a way to write small programs - embedded in the excel workbook - in other programming languages other than VB or VBA.   e.g. Java, C++, C etc

1) These programs should work with predefined worksheets for Input and Output of the workbook - no DB involved.

2) The code has to be in a compiled form so that it is not easily deciphered or edited.

3) It is embedded as part of the workbook.

Comment: VBA is the only solution if you want to embed the code in the spreadsheet. However, you can make the VBA call an external program written in any language. The external application will need a library to interact with the Excel file.

Comment: "2) The code has to be in a compiled form so that it is not easily deciphered or edited." What's your intention with this? If you do as Zoff suggests and have VBA code run an external program, there will be no way to make that VBA indecipherable to someone committed to accessing it. That's kind of the point of Excel only allowing VBA - the workbook identifies itself as "Macro-Enabled", to prevent malicious code from being unknowlingly run.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I understand that VBA code is open.  Thus wanted to figure out the way to write code in other languages.  @Zoff's suggestion will work and maybe the only option.  This workbook - would be part of an offical application deployment  - thus the concept of malicious code - is not a context as part of the company agreements.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634126/can-we-write-a-macro-in-c-sharp-for-excel). You can't natively write macros in excel using anything but VBA but you can create add-ins.

Comment: If the only reason why you're looking for a different language is to hide the code, why not password protect it? If you set a password at the Project Properties dialog box, users will still be able to run the macro, just not view code.

Comment: Depending on how sensitive your data is this would be a great solution. If you have a particularly tech savvy user excel password protection is weak.     You don't have to look very hard around the internet to find scripts to crack excel passwords.